# Cauchy Problem and continuity of derivatives

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I've been asked to solve the Cauchy problem:

> $ \left\{\begin{matrix}
> 2u_{x}+3u_{y}=0  & \hspace{0.1cm} (1)\\ 
>  u(x,0)=|x| & \hspace{0.2cm} (2)&
> \end{matrix}\right. $

Using the method of characteristics I have obtained the solution:

> $ u(x,y)=|x-\frac{2y}{3}| $

Then I am asked if $u \in \mathbb{C}^1(\mathbb{R}^2) $. So I have answered it is not, as it is not differentiable for the set of $\mathbb{R}^2 $  $x-\frac{2y}{3}=0 $.

Assuming this is correct, my question is:

- If we substitute $|x|$ for any function $\phi \in \mathbb{C}^i(\mathbb{R})$ in **(2)**, Can we assure the solution $u(x,y) \in \mathbb{C}^i(\mathbb{R}^2)$?

Comment: I think you mean $\phi \in C^i(\mathbb{R})$, since $\phi$ has only one variable...

Comment: @Chappers correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution will be
$$
u(x,y)=\phi\Bigl(x-\frac{2\,y}{3}\Bigr).
$$
It will have the same regularity as $\phi$. In points where $\phi$ is not $C^1$, the solution must be understood in a *weak* sense.

Comment: @WillieWong Right, I was thinking wave equation.